# Housekeeping script improvements

Tags: python, design-patterns, json

I have built a housekeeping script and I would like to improve it.
I have a JSON file with the details such as directory path, number of days after which the directory or file should be zipped, deletion period for the zip as well as if it's files or directories that we are zipping.

Config JSON file:

```
{
"foo": [
    {
        "path": "/the/directory/to/be/zipped/",
        "nr_files_not_zip": "7",
        "deletion_period": "7",
        "file_or_directory": "files"
    }

]
```

}

For housekeeping, I have tried to use a factory design pattern as there are potentially different file selection requirements but for the moment I am only selecting the files to be zipped based on their mod date.
The script loads the config and creates the housekeeping object through a factory method. Then based on the zip period, deletion period as well as the zip-type it zips and deletes the appropriate files or directories.

I have been using python for a couple of years and I trying to improve. I would really appreciate any feedback regarding the code improvements and best practices.
The housekeeping script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import abc
import os
import sys
import json
import datetime
import time 
import zipfile
import shutil

#abstract housekeeping
class housekeeping(object):
    
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def pick_files(self):
        pass 
    
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def files_to_be_zipped(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def sort_deletion(self):
        pass 
    
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_type(self):
        pass 

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_directory(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_deletion_period(self):
        pass

#houskeeping foo concrete class 
class housekeeping_foo(housekeeping):
    def __init__(self,directory, normal_files,zipped_files,nr_to_leave,deletion_period,type_to_zip):
        self.normal_files = normal_files
        self.zipped_files = zipped_files
        self.nr_to_leave = nr_to_leave
        self.deletion_period = deletion_period
        self.directory = directory
        self.type_to_zip = type_to_zip

    #grabs the files, directories and zip files and stores them in a specif hashmap  
    def pick_files(self):
        for dir_name, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(self.directory):
                for file_name in fileList:
                full_path = dir_name + "/" + file_name
                if os.path.exists(full_path) and not file_name.startswith('.'):
                        if not full_path.endswith('.zip') and not full_path.endswith('.gz'):
                                mod_time = os.path.getmtime(full_path)
                                last_modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mod_time)
                                self.normal_files.update({full_path: last_modified_date})
                        else: 
                                mod_time = os.path.getmtime(full_path)
                                last_modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mod_time)
                                self.zipped_files.update({full_path: last_modified_date})
        return self.normal_files, self.zipped_files


    #removes the files which not be zipped. Based on the mod date for this particular object
    def files_to_be_zipped(self):
        for key, value in self.normal_files.items():
                str_date = value.date()
                today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
                difference = str(today - str_date)
                if "days" in difference:
                    date = difference.split(" ", 1)[0]
                else:
                    date = 0
            
                if int(date) > int(self.nr_to_leave):
                    print("file to be zipped")
                else:
                    del self.normal_files[key]
        return self.normal_files

    #removes the files which should not be included in deletion
    def sort_deletion(self):
            for key, value in self.zipped_files.items():
                    time_since_insertion = str(datetime.datetime.now() - value)
                    if "days" in time_since_insertion:
                        days = int(time_since_insertion.split(' ',1)[0])
                    else:
                        days = 0  
                    if days < int(self.deletion_period):
                            del self.zipped_files[key]
            return self.zipped_files
    #return zip type
    def get_type(self):
        return self.type_to_zip
    #return directory 
    def get_directory(self):
        return self.directory
    #return deletion period 
    def get_deletion_period(self):
        return self.deletion_period



class housekeeping_factory:
    def create_housekeeping(self,name, directory, normal_files,zipped_files,nr_to_leave,deletion_period,type_to_zip):
        if name == "foo":
            return housekeeping_foo(directory,normal_files,zipped_files,nr_to_leave,deletion_period,type_to_zip)

#loading JSON config file 
def load_config(directory_name):
    with open('housekeeping.config.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for config_items in data[directory_name]:
            directory_name_wih_full_path = config_items["path"]
                        nr_to_leave = config_items["nr_files_not_zip"]
                        deletion_period = config_items["deletion_period"]
                        type_to_zip = config_items["file_or_directory"]
    return directory_name_wih_full_path, nr_to_leave, deletion_period, type_to_zip

#creates the housekeeping object strips the files and directories which should not be included in the zipping or deletion
def housekeeping_client():
    normal_files = {}
    zipped_files = {}
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        directory_name = sys.argv[1]
        directory_name_wih_full_path, nr_to_leave, deletion_period, type_to_zip = load_config(directory_name)
        factory = housekeeping_factory()
        housekeeping_shape = factory.create_housekeeping(directory_name, directory_name_wih_full_path,normal_files,zipped_files,nr_to_leave,deletion_period,type_to_zip)
        housekeeping_shape.pick_files()
        files_to_zip = housekeeping_shape.files_to_be_zipped()
        to_delete = housekeeping_shape.get_deletion_period()
        if to_delete != "NA":
            file_to_del = housekeeping_shape.sort_deletion()
        else: 
            file_to_del = {}
        zip_type = housekeeping_shape.get_type()
        file_directory = housekeeping_shape.get_directory()
        run_housekeeping_client(files_to_zip,file_to_del,zip_type, file_directory)
        
    else:
        print("Wrong number of arguments...")

#depending on the zip type a zip directory or zip file methods will be called 
def run_housekeeping_client(files_to_zip,file_to_del,zip_type, file_directory):
    for key, value in files_to_zip.items():
        directory_full_path_with_file =  key
        if zip_type == "files":
            zip_the_file(key, key)
            os.remove(directory_full_path_with_file)
        elif zip_type == "directory":
            zip_the_directory(key)
            shutil.rmtree(directory_full_path_with_file)
    ####################################################
    if len(file_to_del.keys()) != 0:
        for key, value in file_to_del.items():
            directory_full_path_with_file =  key
            os.remove(directory_full_path_with_file)

#zipping directories
def zip_the_directory(dir_name):
    file_with_zip =  dir_name
    file_to_zip = dir_name + ".zip"
    zip_File = zipfile.ZipFile(file_to_zip,'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    directory_path = dir_name.split("/")[-1]
    lenDirPath = len(directory_path)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_with_zip):
            for file in files:
                    filePath = os.path.join(root, file)
                        zip_File.write(filePath , filePath[lenDirPath :])
        zip_File.close()


#zipping files
def zip_the_file(file_name):
    file_with_zip = file_name + ".zip"
    file_to_zip = file_name
    directory_path = file_name.split("/")[-1]
    len_dir_path = len(directory_path)
        with zipfile.ZipFile(file_with_zip, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_file:
            zip_file.write(file_to_zip, file_to_zip[len_dir_path :])
        print("file has been zipped")

if __name__== '__main__':
        housekeeping_client()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class housekeeping(object):
    
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
```

looks nicer as

```
class housekeeping(metaclass = abc.ABCMeta):
```

This isn't Java, you don't need getter methods for your properties - just access them directly. On a related note, your factory method doesn't need a class, it can just be a normal function.

I'm not quite sure what this code is supposed to do (from `files_to_be_zipped`), but it seems incredibly hacky. Shouldn't `date = (today - str_date).days` do the same thing? Same thing for similar code in `sort_deletion`.

```
difference = str(today - str_date)
if "days" in difference:
    date = difference.split(" ", 1)[0]
else:
    date = 0
```

Why is this a loop? You only ever return the last item's values. Just remove the extraneous array from the config file. And I think this is an indent error anyways.

```
def load_config(directory_name):
    with open('housekeeping.config.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for config_items in data[directory_name]:
            directory_name_wih_full_path = config_items["path"]
                        nr_to_leave = config_items["nr_files_not_zip"]
                        deletion_period = config_items["deletion_period"]
                        type_to_zip = config_items["file_or_directory"]
    return directory_name_wih_full_path, nr_to_leave, deletion_period, type_to_zip
```

These lines should be moved to a separate function (or even a concrete method on the ABC) to separate the input handling from the actual housekeeping code.

```
        housekeeping_shape.pick_files()
        files_to_zip = housekeeping_shape.files_to_be_zipped()
        to_delete = housekeeping_shape.get_deletion_period()
        if to_delete != "NA":
            file_to_del = housekeeping_shape.sort_deletion()
        else: 
            file_to_del = {}
        zip_type = housekeeping_shape.get_type()
        file_directory = housekeeping_shape.get_directory()
        run_housekeeping_client(files_to_zip,file_to_del,zip_type, file_directory)
```

`run_housekeeping_client` seems misnamed - it never does anything related to the housekeeping class.

You also have an inconsistent naming convention - some of your variables are in `camelCase` instead of `snake_case` (as recommended by PEP 8).

Answer (score 2):

I noticed some of your indentation appears wrong in the code you have provided, so I'll not be able to comment on those particular sections as my assumptions could be invalid.

But the first thing I would suggest is to look into the `Pathlib` library since you are dealing with files, for example here's my refactoring of your `pick_files` method:

```py
from pathlib import Path

class housekeeping_foo(housekeeping):
    def __init__(self, directory, normal_files, zipped_files, nr_to_leave, deletion_period, type_to_zip):
        ...
        ...
        self.directory = Path(directory)
        ...

    def pick_files(self):
        for item in self.directory.iterdir():
            if item.is_file() and not item.name.startswith("."):
                modification_time = os.path.getmtime(str(item))
                last_modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(modification_time)
                if item.suffix in (".gz", ".zip"):
                    self.zipped_files.update({str(item): last_modified_date})
                else:
                    self.normal_files.update({str(item): last_modified_date})
        return self.normal_files, self.zipped_files
```

I find it much easier to read vs. using os.path and its assistants.  Outside of using Pathlib, I also made some other changes:

1. I moved the `modification_time` and `last_modified_date` variables up above the if statement as these were common to both branches.
2. Another thing I changed was I check if the suffix (the extension) of the file is either ".gz" or ".zip" by checking if the extension is in a tuple, this avoids having to have two if statements as before.
3. Since we were also acting on both if it was a compressed file and if it wasn't, I switched the logic around to avoid having a `not` statement (I think it's easier to read, you may disagree).

Another thing that jumps out at me that the other commentor has also talked about is the `load_config` method.  Personally I would avoid returning more than 2 values from a method like you have here, instead I would just return the dictionary like so:

```py
def load_config(directory_name):
    with open("housekeeping.config.json") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        return data[directory_name]
```

then you can pass this config object through to the `create_housekeeping` method on the factory to access the items within it:

```
    def create_housekeeping(self, name, normal_files, zipped_files, config):
        if name == "foo":
            return housekeeping_foo(
                config['directory'],
                normal_files,
                zipped_files,
                config['nr_to_leave'],
                config['deletion_period'],
                config['type_to_zip'],
            )
```

This means the 'knowledge' of which config items are needed is stored in the factory, and the `load_config` method deals with just that, loading all of the config.

You could even take it a step further and pass the config through again to the objects constructor.

These are just two things I felt I could easily contribute with, but if you'd like any more feedback on a specific area or want to ask a question please feel free to do so!